# Windows POS Ready 2009 Hangs On Boot

Tags: windows

Cannot find a lot of literature on this subject.

Background: Company has a Point-of-sale computer, that lost power to the business, and was only plugged into a surge protector. When the power returned, the computer did not. It is running Windows POS Ready 2009, which is an off-shoot of Windows XP. The problem is that it hangs on boot (hence the title). In going into Safe Mode, the last item loaded is Mup.sys. I don't know if this is what is hanging the system, or if it is just the last item loaded, but I never make it to the Windows XP screen. (POS Ready 2009 is based on Windows XP).

I was able to boot into UBCD for Windows, using a Windows XP installation disk. I performed tests on the memory and HDD, which both came back fine. I swapped out the HDD and RAM card, plugged in a USB CD ROM drive, loaded up the installation disk, and it freezes after "Starting Installation Environment".

In my last bit of troubleshooting, I swapped the power pack, and it was still a no-go. I examined the motherboard, and did not see any bad capacitors or anything that appeared to be 'fried'. Has anyone else been in this situation and could offer some advice, or perhaps another troubleshooting tactic? My last resort is swapping out the mobo, but I want to make sure that's my last resort.

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: FYI: "the last item loaded is Mup.sys. I don't know if this is what is hanging the system, or if it is just the last item loaded" -- It means that MUP.SYS was the last thing (successfully) loaded. Not that that helps you much, but I figured I'd clear that up for you. ;)

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if there would be another driver after it that is trying to load and cannot, either due to it being corrupt or a hardware failure. I am unable to find a list of loaded items, however.

Comment: Who in their right mind name a software that abbreviates "POS", oh, MS would.

Comment: @Moab "Point Of Sale" wasn't coined by MS. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_sale#History) They wish. ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 ok, who did?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you can't install a fresh copy of Windows (especially to a new HDD as well as problems with the old), then you have hardware problem, as you aren't even getting to the point where system-specific drivers are kicking in.

Since you've already tried (assuming known-good) RAM, HDD and PSU, then there's not much left other than the MB.

Unfortunately, 9 times out of 10 when a motherboard fails there will be no visible defects. You just have to try swapping I a known-good tester/replacement.